# Divide int and return a float

Tags: iphone, objective-c, function

I have a problem that I can not fix with a number, I'll explain.
At one point in my code I call a function that returns an int, then I divide it and have a float with two decimal places.

My Ex 69033792 Fuzion back, I want to have to divide by 1024 and 67415.81
I write

```
NSInteger mem_0 = [self printMemoryInfo:@"0"];
    [self.mem1 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",(mem_0/1024f)]];
```

but I do not return the decimal part ... What's wrong?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
myDouble = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init]; 
[myDouble setFormatterBehavior:NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4]; 
[myDouble setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[myDouble setRoundingMode:NSNumberFormatterRoundHalfUp];
[myDouble setMinimumFractionDigits:0];
[myDouble setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
    NSInteger mem_0 = [self printMemoryInfo:@"0"];
    [self.mem1 setText:[myDouble stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble: mem_0/1024]]];
    [myDouble release];
```

Comment: i try this code but in first line xcode say "use of undeclared identifier myDouble"

Comment: Yes, sorry for this. Replace the first line with: NSNumberFormatter *myDouble = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];

Answer (score 1):

You should be getting the compile-time error "Invalid digit 'f' in decimal constant", because `1024f` is not legal.  You need to say it like this:

```
[self.mem1 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",(mem_0/1024.0f)]];
```

or you can just say `1024.0` without the `f`, because it will be passed to `stringWithFormat:` as a double anyway.